# Дата в формат mysql

Tags: php, mysql, дата

Ребят подскажите как преобразовать дату в виде "26 августа" в вид "2017-08-26" на PHP.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function date2mysql($date) {
    $trans = [
        'января' => 'jan',
        'февраля' => 'feb',
        'марта' => 'mar',
        'апреля' => 'apr',
        'мая' => 'may',
        'июня' => 'jun',
        'июля' => 'jul',
        'августа' => 'aug',
        'сентября' => 'sen',
        'октября' => 'oct',
        'ноября' => 'nov',
        'декабря' => 'dec',
    ];
    return date("Y-m-d", strtotime(strtr($date, $trans)));
}    

echo date2mysql('26 августа');
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php 

$full_date = '26 августа';

$month = substr($full_date,3);
$day = substr($full_date,0,2);


switch($month){
    case "января"   : $month = "01"; break;
    case "февраля"  : $month = "02"; break;
    case "марта"    : $month = "03"; break;
    case "апреля"   : $month = "04"; break;
    case "мая"      : $month = "05"; break;
    case "июня"     : $month = "06"; break;
    case "июля"     : $month = "07"; break;
    case "августа"  : $month = "08"; break;
    case "сентября" : $month = "09"; break;
    case "октября"  : $month = "10"; break;
    case "ноября"   : $month = "11"; break;
    case "декабря"  : $month = "12"; break;
}

$new_full = date('Y')."-".$month."-".$day;

echo $new_full;
```

Comment: а зачем здесь последняя строчка?

Comment: согласен, строка лишняя

Answer (score -2):

Вот так решил вопрос!

```
$video_time = '26 августа';
$day_old = explode(' ', $video_time);  
                $day_old = $day_old[1]; 
$video_date_month_old = end(explode(' ', $video_time)); 
                $video_game_year = date('Y');  
                if ($video_date_month_old == 'января') { $video_date_month = '01'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'февраля') { $video_date_month = '02'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'марта') { $video_date_month = '03'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'апреля') { $video_date_month = '04'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'мая') { $video_date_month = '05'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'июня') { $video_date_month = '06'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'июля') { $video_date_month = '07'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'августа') { $video_date_month = '08'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'сентября') { $video_date_month = '09'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'октября') { $video_date_month = '10'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'ноября') { $video_date_month = '11'; } 
                elseif ($video_date_month_old == 'декабря') { $video_date_month = '12'; }

$video_full_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($day_old.'-'.$video_date_month.'-'.$video_game_year));
```